# Laravel 8, image url rerieved from database does not return image

Tags: laravel

I have been struggling with this problem for quite a few hours. My problem is that I have an image url saved in my database and when i retrieve it I try to display it in my index.blade.php. The weird part is I had used the same code in an older project and it worked, but I turned on the older project and it does not work there anymore either. I have done `php artisan storage:link` and from what i see the link is correct but the images are displayed as broken, I have looked up various solution but all of it lead to a dead end, because the url just doesnt want to display the image. The image url is saved in this form http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/public/vsX9ihmRknGWLXtNRmxgCXV3ckqhlFoBlyuMoejB.png

My index.blade.php tbody

```
  <tbody>
    @foreach($companies as $company)
        <tr>
            <td scope="row">{{$company->id}}</td>
            <td>{{$company->name}}</td>
            <td>{{$company->email}}</td>
            <td><img class="class='img-fluid rounded mb-3 mb-lg-0 ml-md-0" src="{{$company->logo}}"></td>
            <td>{{$company->url}}</td>
            <td>
                <a href="{{route('company.edit', $company->id)}}" class="float-left">
                    <button type="button"
                            class="btn btn-primary mr-2">{{__('Edit')}}</button>
                </a>
                <form action="{{route('company.delete',$company->id)}}" method="POST"
                      class="float-left">
                    {{method_field('DELETE')}}
                    @csrf
                    <button type="submit"
                            class="btn btn-danger btn-sn">{{__('Delete')}}</button>
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
```

How I call it from my Companiescontroller

```
 public function index(): Renderable
{
    $companies = $this->company->all();

    return view('company.index', compact('companies'));
}
```

How I store my image url

```
   public function store(Request $request): RedirectResponse
    {
    $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => '',
        'logo' => 'dimensions:min_width:100,min_height:100',
        'url' => ''
    ]);
    $parameters = $request->all();
    if ($request->logo !== null) {
        $image = $request->logo->store('public');
        $parameters['logo'] = URL::to('/') . '/storage/' . $image;
    }
    $this->company->create($parameters);

    return redirect()->route('company.index');
}
```

I am not sure if this is enough, but i guess these are primary parts.

Comment: By default `php artisan storage:link` create a symlink with `storage/app/public` so move your image from `storage/public` to `storage/app/public`.  Then you can access through `http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/vsX9ihmRknGWLXtNRmxgCXV3ckqhlFoBlyuMoejB.png`

Comment: Thank you, you are a lifesaver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `php artisan storage:link` create a symlink with `storage/app/public` so move your image from `storage/public` to `storage/app/public`. Then you can access through `http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/vsX9ihmRknGWLXtNRmxgCXV3ckqhlFoBlyuMoejB.png`